# Can I use Cloudflare with Tumblr or cache images manually?

Tags: domains, images, cache, cloudflare, tumblr

I've just setup Cloudflare on my tumblr blog (with custom domain).

1) As I understand it, this was actually pointless because images on tumblr blogs are hosted on `media.tumblr.com/.../inline.jpg` and not on my domain?

2) If yes it was pointless, can I cache / host images manually on Cloudflare?

3) Should I remove Cloudflare again or is there other benefits of using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tumblr is a big website with a ton of images.   Any website of that size with that many images is already going to be using a content delivery network (CDN) for the images.  When you use a CDN for images, you usually have put them onto a separate subdomain.  Tumblr has done so; another indication that they are using a CDN.

Because your site is hosted by tumblr, and they already use a CDN, you can remove Cloudflare.   It isn't doing anything that Tumblr isn't doing already.